# Cross Domain Cookies

Tags: apex, visualforce, website-integration, cookies

I need help in one of my projects's requirement to set a cross domain cookies which later can be accessed by a server when we hit a URL from Salesforce's VF page.

Please let me know if someone had similar experience.